# Is the following function bounded or no?

Tags: functions

Is the following function bounded or no?
$$g(x) = 3 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{9-x^2}},$$

My professor said that it is not bounded as $g(x) \geq \frac{11}{3}$, but when I solved I found that $ 3 + \frac{2}{3} \leq g(x) < 3$ , so what is right ?

Thanks!!

Comment: How can g (x) < 3 if $\sqrt {9-x^2}\ge 0$?

Comment: And how can g (x) \le 3 +\frac 23$ if $\sqrt {9-x^2}\le 3$?

Comment: Btw $a > c< b$ is not a proper statement.  You mean $a>c $ and $b>c $.  You can't combine them like that.  You can combine them as $c< \min (a,b)$.  But you did this wrong as $g (x)>3$ and $g (x)\ge 3+\frac 23$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not bounded since $f(x) \to +\infty$ when $x \to 3^{-}$.